# PowerBI DAX Create Table of Hours from Project List and Start of Week Table

Tags: powerbi, iteration, dax, union

I am trying to create a new table that contains a column with start of week and the hours estimated to be spent for that week on a per project basis.

| Start of Week | Project | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/20/2022 | ABC_XXX | 10 |
| 6/27/2022 | ABC_XXX | 10 |
| 6/20/2022 | ABC_YYY | 40 |
| 6/27/2022 | ABC_YYY | 40 |

I have a table of dates representing the start of week for every project in the project table.
week start date = [date]-weekday([date],2)+1

| Start of Week |
| --- |
| 6/20/2022 |
| 6/27/2022 |
| 7/4/2022 |

The project table contains (among other things) the project name, estimated start date, duration, and hours per week.

| Project Name | Estimated Start Date | Duration in weeks | Hours Per Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC_XXX | 6/13/2022 | 8 | 10 |
| ABC_YYY | 6/04/2022 | 27 | 40 |

I am having trouble getting off the starting line.  I know I need to evaluate on a per project basis and loop through all of the dates in my date table but can't find a good method to start with.  I have done a lot of more simple things with creating new tables and calculations but this one is a little more complicated for me to get started.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The ultimate goal for this data is to present a trend showing estimated project demand over time that can be filtered by project or summed across all projects as well as filtered by timeline and displayed in a calendar view but it all starts with getting the data into this format I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Power Query solution. The steps in the code below are:

1. use Date.AddWeeks to calculate the end date
2. [List dates between two dates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3HLseZxSj4)
3. Expand the list of dates and convert to date format
4. Use Date.DayOfWeek to create a day of week column
5. filter the table for day of week = 1 to include only weekly values (starting on Monday)

.

```
 let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnRyjo+IiFDSUTLTNzTWNzIwMgKyLYDY0EApVgeiIDIyEqzABCZvZA4kTBAKoqKigALmCAVAOaAqpdhYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Project Name" = _t, #"Estimated Start Date" = _t, #"Duration in weeks" = _t, #"Hours Per Week" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project Name", type text}, {"Estimated Start Date", type date}, {"Duration in weeks", Int64.Type}, {"Hours Per Week", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Estimated End Date", each Date.AddWeeks([Estimated Start Date],[Duration in weeks])),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "dates", each {Number.From([Estimated Start Date])..Number.From([Estimated End Date])}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "dates"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"dates", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "day of week", each Date.DayOfWeek([dates])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom4", each ([day of week] = 1))
    in
        #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Strictly Funk.  Give me a little to have a run at this.  I have not used Power Query yet so I will dig in and get back with you.

Comment: This helped a ton.  I ended up using the DAX solution from the original thread that was in your link to create the week column.  ProposalWeeklyData = 

  FILTER(

      CROSSJOIN('WeekStartDates', ProjectProposal_uv),

      ProjectProposal_uv[EstStartDate] <= 'WeekStartDates'[week start date] &&

      ProjectProposal_uv[EstEndDate] >= 'WeekStartDates'[week start date]

)  https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/M-Power-Query-help-for-table-merge-Conditional-Cross-Join/m-p/480393#M223598